# css - I've got a nested floating div, how do I get it to fill the entire 100%?

Tags: html, css

I've got a floating div.
That div is nested inside an html element that recieves its height from one of its children.
How do I get my div to stick to the bottom?

Here's  a sample of my problem. I want to get my "Hello all" to the bottom of the parent.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;border:1px solid green;clear:both">

<div style="float:left">
  <p> Hi All </p>      
</div>

<div style="height:150px;width:50px; background-color:red;float:left">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you open to using Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: I'd rather not. I really want just plain css if possible

Comment: Wrap it in another Relative DIV and place it Absolutely at the bottom.

Comment: @Dan that doesn't work, I tried it.  It will not take up width causing the red box to align overlap it.

Comment: I do what Dan says on my web site - www.timmorgan.us - for my header and footer menus. I place them below the HTML content and pull them to the right locations through CSS.

Comment: is the missing `<\div>` on purpose

Comment: I suspect that the missing `<\div>` was on purpose but the missing `</div>` was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/j742b/1/) together. Here's the CSS:

```
#cont {
    margin:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid green;
    clear:both;
}
#rel {
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
}
#abs {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
#red {
    height:150px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div id="cont">
    <div id="rel">
        <div id="abs">
            <p>Hi All</p>      
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="red">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm still using the position:relative/absolute trick, but instead of floating the divs, I'm making them inline-blocks. This way it has the same effect as when you float them.

Comment: You can use vertical-align on inline-blocks, it will be easier. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/48H2g/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:absolute` to make an element stick to the bottom of its parent:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;border:1px solid green;clear:both; position: relative;">

<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; background: #fff;">
  <p> Hi All, if you make this long it will stick to the bottom of the parent container.</p>      
</div>

<div style="height:150px;width:50px; background-color:red;float:left">
</div>
</div>
```

Notice the `position:relative` on the container element (in order for a child element to use `position:absolute` its parent must have its `position` set to something other than `static` which is the default).

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/mJXxM/2/

Comment: I was gonna post this, but it interferes with the red div. Maybe that's a problem?

Comment: The absolutely positioned element will overlap the relatively positioned (red) one. You can set a background color of the absolutely positioned element so it appears as though the relatively positioned one stops short of the bottom of the container. You can also specify height values for both of the child divs so they don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want (as suggested by Dan):

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;border:1px solid green;clear:both; position: relative;">

<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px">
  <p> Hi All </p>      
</div>

<div style="height:150px;width:50px; background-color:red;float:left"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Half of your problem would probably be due to the fact that you have an extra `<div>` tag with no closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: I think that vondip probably just omitted a closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: This answer has been flagged *three times.*  Mods aren't going to delete it, because we don't know if it is an answer or not.  So, if you dislike this answer, please just downvote it and be done.  Also, [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113304/is-there-a-way-to-respond-to-declines-on-flags).